# Mapping of list elements of class with dozer xml mapping file

Tags: list, class, dozer

There are two classes named Class1 and Class2.
Class1 have a list of ClassA objects.
Class2 have a list of ClassB objects.

Class1 is like below :-

```
public class Class1
 {
  private String number_1;
   private List<ClassA> classA= new ArrayList<ClassA>();
  }
   //all getters and setters
```

ClassA is like :-

```
public class ClassA
{
  private string name_A;
  private int rollnum_A;
}
   //all getters and setters
```

Class2 is like :-

```
public class Class1
 {
  private String number_1;
   private List<ClassB> classB= new ArrayList<ClassB>();
  }
   //all getters and setters
```

ClassB is like

```
public class ClassB
{
  private string name_B;
  private int rollnum_B;
}
   //all getters and setters
```

Below is the dozer file that i have created :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
      http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">


<mapping>
    <class-a>Class1</class-a>
    <class-b>Class2</class-b>

    <field>
    <a>number_1</a>
    <b>number_2</b>
    </field>

    <field>
    <a>name_A</a>
        <b>name_B</b>
        <a-hint>ClassA</a-hint>
        <b-hint>ClassB</b-hint>
    </field>

    <field>
    <a>rollnum_B</a>
        <b>rollnum_B</b>
        <a-hint>ClassA</a-hint>
        <b-hint>ClassB</b-hint>
    </field>


</mapping>
</mappings>
```

But its not working.. Is there any other way to map list of class objects.

Answer (score 1):

The correct definition for mapping file is as follows

```
<mappings>
<mapping type="bi-directional">
    <class-a>Class1</class-a>
    <class-b>Class2</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>classA</a>
        <b>classB</b>
        <a-hint>ClassA</a-hint>
        <b-hint>ClassB</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
<mapping type="bi-directional">
    <class-a>ClassA</class-a>
    <class-b>ClassB</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>name_A</a>
        <b>name_B</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>rollnum_A</a>
        <b>rollnum_B</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

in a-hint, b-hint, class-a and class-b tags must place the location of the class example:

```
<class-a>com.project.model.Class1</class-a>
<class-b>com.project.model.Class2</class-b>

<a-hint>com.project.model.ClassA</a-hint>
```

`<b-hint>com.project.model.ClassB</b-hint>`

a-hint and b-hint are declared only when the data type is different.

Primitive type variables can be left without mapping, but only if these have the same name in each class. In your case, it were mapped because they had diferent names.